# loading youtube videos through xml do not dismiss default progress bar in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, webview, android-youtube-api

I have created an application where i fetch youtube id from backend and then append it on to webview to display list of youtube videos in my recylerview. Everything works absolutely fine but only problem is i do not from where the default progreebar is continuously been shown even after all videos are loaded. i want to dismiss this default progress bar.

Here is the code of adapter

```
class YoutubeAdapter(internal var context: Context, internal var youtubevideosList: List<YoutubeModel>, recyclerView: RecyclerView) : RecyclerView.Adapter<YoutubeAdapter.MViewHolder>() {


    internal var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    internal var progressBar:ProgressBar?=null

    init {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
        this.progressBar=ProgressBar(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.youtube_row, parent, false)

        return MViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MViewHolder, position: Int) {


        //val youtubeid = "Wn8-CsL_lg4"

        val youtubeid = youtubevideosList.get(position).getYoutubeID()
        //val youtubelink = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+youtubeid+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
        val youtubelink1 = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtubeid\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"

        holder.youTubePlayerView.loadData(youtubelink1, "text/html", "utf-8")
        //holder.descTextview.text=youtubevideosList.get(position).getVideoDesc()


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return youtubevideosList.size
    }



    inner class MViewHolder(internal var view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        internal var youTubePlayerView: WebView
        internal var descTextview: TextView
        internal var progressBar:ProgressBar?=null

        init {

            youTubePlayerView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.webVideoView) as WebView
            descTextview = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.describtion_tv) as TextView

            youTubePlayerView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
            progressBar= ProgressBar(context)
           /* youTubePlayerView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {

            })*/


        }
    }
}
```

I haven't declared my progressbar anywhere but from where it is continuously been shown?

Answer (score 0):

In both your YoutubeAdapter class and your MViewHolder inner class you had declare and them initialize a progress bar. Why you said you haven't?

In YoutubeAdapter class delete:

```
internal var progressBar:ProgressBar?=null
```

And

```
this.progressBar=ProgressBar(context)
```

In MViewHolder class delete:

```
internal var progressBar:ProgressBar?=null
```

And

```
progressBar=ProgressBar(context)
```